# how to normalize my image data in Tensorflow Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, normalization

As mentioned I'm trying to normalize my dataset before training my model. I was using `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` to do this previously.

```
        train_data = tf.cast(train_data, tf.float32)
        train_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
            featurewise_center=True,
            featurewise_std_normalization=True
        )
        train_gen.fit(train_data)
        train_generator = train_gen.flow(train_data, train_labels,
                                         batch_size=batch_size,
                                         shuffle=True)
        model.fit(train_generator, epochs=base_epochs)
```

However, I had to give it up because I implemented a complicated loss function using a custom layer. Therefore data and labels are required to be sent to the model separately as inputs. Is there any other function provided in Tensorflow Keras to normalize my samples?

Comment: These are simple operations that you can implement yourself (if somehow you can't use the generator).

Comment: You can try out with numpy array, but, it will not be batch wise as you've mentioned in ImageDataGenerator. np.mean(train_data, axis=0) and then train_data -= train_data_mean. Similarly, for std, np.std along axis 0 for all the samples.

Comment: @AkashKumar  Thanks for your kind suggestions! I solved the problem after checking the source code and did exactly as you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    def standardize(image_data):
        image_data -= np.mean(image_data, axis=0)
        image_data /= np.std(image_data, axis=0)
        return image_data
```

It's an easy method to solve the problem. Preprocessing the data myself.

Comment: For other readers, this is implementing [standard scoring (aka z-scoring)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score)